# Android - Wait for a thread to execute before starting a service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service

In my application I am employing a service that uses a dictionary loaded from the server. I load the dictionary in a separate thread before calling the service. I want to know how to start the service ONLY after the dictionary has been completely loaded because when i try to access the dictionary inside the service it returns null.

**MainActivity.java**

```
onCreate(){
     ...
     doFunction();
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceA.class);
     startService(intent);
}

private void doFunction(){
    ClassThread().getInstance().process();
}
```

**ClassThread.java**

```
public class ClassThread{
 ....
 public void process(){
   final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback(){
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage (Message msg){
            if(msg.arg1 == 1){
                loadDictionary();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    final Message message = new Message();

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            message.arg1 = 1;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest an alternate approach: why not use an `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread` ? Load the dictionary data in `doInBackground()`, and call `startService()` in `onPostExecute()`. No messy thread synchronization required.

The `AsyncTask` abstraction was designed to be used in conjunction with Android's single UI thread policy in order to avoid precisely these kinds of awkward synchronization problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's [AsynchTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)!